# How to make two requests in one request with rxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am accessing the server in my Android app. I want to get a list of my friends and a list of friend requests in different queries. They have to come at the same time. Then I want to show this data on the screen.

I tried to get data from two queries at using flatMap.
`interactor.getColleagues()` and `interactor.getTest()` returns the data type `Observable<List<Colleagues>>`

```
private fun loadColleaguesEmployer() {
        if (disposable?.isDisposed == true) disposable?.dispose()
        //запрос на список друзей
        interactor.getColleagues(view.getIdUser() ?: preferences.userId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap {
                interactor.getTest().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext {
                            result-> view.showTest(mapper.map(result))
                    }
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { result1 ->
                    //Обработка списка коллег работодателей
                    view.showColleagues(mapper.map(result1.filter { data -> data.typeFriend == "Работодатель" }))
                },
                onError = { it.printStackTrace() }
            )
    }
```

I want to get and process data from different queries at the same time.

Comment: You can try to remove `interactor.getTest()` from `flatMap` and create separate `fun`. Then call it one by one instead of adding to query

Answer (score 0):

> Zip combine the emissions of multiple Observables together via a
>   specified function

You can use **Zip (rx Java)** http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html, some sudo code will be like this -

```
val firstApiObserver = apIs.hitFirstApiFunction(//api parameters)
val secondApiObserver = apIs.hitSecondApiFunction(//api parameters)

val zip: Single<SubscriptionsZipper>//SubscriptionsZipper is the main model which contains first& second api response model ,
zip = Single.zip(firstApiObserver, secondApiObserver, BiFunction { firstApiResponseModel,secondApiResponseModel -> SubscriptionsZipper(firstApiResponseModelObjectInstance, secondApiResponseModelObjectInstance) })

zip.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<SubscriptionsZipper> {
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                compositeDisposable.add(d)
            }

            override fun onSuccess(subscriptionsZipper: SubscriptionsZipper) {
                Utils.hideProgressDialog()
               //here you will get both api response together
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Utils.hideProgressDialog()
            }
        })
```

Hope it helps you .

Comment: @Павел-Филимонов hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

**Combining observable results of multiple async http requests with rxjava's Observable.zip.**

```
public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Observable<ObservableHttpResponse>> observableRequests = Arrays.asList(
                Http.getAsync("http://localhost:3001/stream"),
                Http.getAsync("http://localhost:3002/stream"),
                Http.getAsync("http://localhost:3003/stream"),
                Http.getAsync("http://localhost:3004/stream"));

        List<Observable<Stats>> observableStats = observableRequests.stream()
                .map(observableRequest ->
                        observableRequest.flatMap(response ->
                                response.getContent()
                                        .map(new EventStreamJsonMapper<>(Stats.class))))
                .collect(toList());

        Observable<List<Stats>> joinedObservables = Observable.zip(
                observableStats.get(0),
                observableStats.get(1),
                observableStats.get(2),
                observableStats.get(3),
                Arrays::asList);

        // This does not work, as FuncN accepts (Object...) https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/functions/FuncN.java#L19
        // Observable<List<Stats>> joinedObservables = Observable.zip(observableStats, Arrays::asList);

        joinedObservables
                .take(10)
                .subscribe(
                        (List<Stats> statslist) -> {
                            System.out.println(statslist);

                            double average = statslist.stream()
                                    .mapToInt(stats -> stats.ongoingRequests)
                                    .average()
                                    .getAsDouble();

                            System.out.println("avg: " + average);
                        },
                        System.err::println,
                        Http::shutdown);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by simple operation zip like

```
private fun callRxJava() {

    RetrofitBase.getClient(context).create(Services::class.java).getApiName()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    getObservable()
        .flatMap(object : io.reactivex.functions.Function<List<User>, Observable<User>> {
            override fun apply(t: List<User>): Observable<User> {
                return Observable.fromIterable(t); // returning user one by one from usersList.
            } // flatMap - to return users one by one

        })


        .subscribe(object : Observer<User> {
            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                showProgressbar()

            }

            override fun onNext(t: User) {
                userList.add(t)
                hideProgressBar()
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Error---", e.message)
                hideProgressBar()
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }


        })

}
```

---

this function combines your response from 2 queries

```
private fun getObservable(): Observable<List<User>> {
    return Observable.zip(
        getCricketFansObservable(),
        getFootlaballFansObservable(),
        object : BiFunction<List<User>, List<User>, List<User>> {
            override fun apply(t1: List<User>, t2: List<User>): List<User> {
                val userList = ArrayList<User>()
                userList.addAll(t1)
                userList.addAll(t2)
                return userList
            }

        })
}
```

---

here is example of first observable

```
fun getCricketFansObservable(): Observable<List<User>> {
    return RetrofitBase.getClient(context).create(Services::class.java).getCricketers().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both observables return the same data type and you don't mind mixing of both sources data - consider using [Observable.merge()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html)

For example:

```
 Observable.merge(interactor.getColleagues(), interactor.getTest())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                    (n) -> {/*do on next*/ },
                    (e) -> { /*do on error*/ });
```

Note, that `.merge()` operator doesn't care about emissions order.